# Excel - Show if a cell (in the same column) has a value below it, not a blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010

I need some help please, I'm trying to save time as I'm working with 100k+ rows.

I'm trying to find a way of finding out when there is information on 2 consecutive cells, one below the other. I've attached an image as it will make more sense than me trying to explain.

[image: Excel Problem]

I need the top cell marked so that I can wrap/combine it with the cell below, if it contains information. If the cell below is blank, then it is fine to leave

Thanks and I hope I make sense!

Comment: Means you want to pull values in `B16` & `B30` ?

Comment: Are the TEXT Identical ?

Comment: Is the goal just to have an indicator (where?) when consecutive cells have values so you can manually adjust it, or to copy or move (which?) the second cell to the next column in the same row?  Can there be more than one consecutive populated row?  Have you researched or tried anything yet?  There are a gazillion ways to test for this condition; can you clarify what aspect of the problem is the hangup?

Comment: So my list contains the name of a company and then information to do with the company in columns to the right. Sometimes the name is so long that it splits down into the cell below. I need a way of marking when this occurs so that I can filter and find this issue so that I can join the split name together again

Comment: I'm thinking i'll probably need an if statement, It's just my formula knowledge is not extensive

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you correctly you are searching to mark the row where both columns have any value. if it's so, then just add a formula to any cell, rather than A or B column :)

```
=AND(A1,B1)
```

if there is any value in both thous cells it will give value "TRUE", else it will give an #value error.

but i think filtering/sorting will be halpfull too. just add a filter and then sort/filter it so that blank cells will not apear or apear in the bottom of the table.

Comment: The question is dealing with text rather than numbers.  Have you tested your solution with text (doesn't work, at least in LO Calc).  AND requires arguments that can represent true or false.

Comment: The text is in the same column, I replied to a comment above which may explain my issue better